# How to create multi-language topics/pages in TWiki?

Tags: perl, twiki

Is there a "standard" way to create multi-language topics in TWiki?

I am preparing a multilanguage site using TWiki as platform. TWiki has a decent I18N support. The user interface is translated into many languages, but **I want to create topics that have content in more than one language**.

Creating separate topics per language would make it hard to maintain. Is there some plugin which allows me to add multi-language content to topics. Switching the user interface to another language would display the corresponding content or fallback to the only available (default) language content.

Answer (score 1):

I found a TWiki plugin which seems to work. it is quite basic but is ok for a start.

http://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Plugins/ForUserLanguagesPlugin

I hope it will scale well.

There is yet another similar plugin but it creates separate topics per language.
http://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Plugins/TopicTranslationsPlugin

Comment: How did the plugin work out for you? Or have you found/used another solution since?